# How should I connect clickhouse to Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, clickhouse

```
CREATE TABLE readings_queue
(

    `readid` Int32,

    `time` DateTime,

    `temperature` Decimal(5,2)
)
ENGINE = Kafka
SETTINGS kafka_broker_list = 'serverIP:9092',
 kafka_topic_list = 'newtest',
 kafka_format = 'CSV',
 kafka_group_name = 'clickhouse_consumer_group',
 kafka_num_consumers = 3
```

Above is the code that I build up connection of Kafka and Clickhouse. But after I execute the code, only the table is created, no data is retrieved.

```
~/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic newtest --from-beginning
1,"2020-05-16 23:55:44",14.2
2,"2020-05-16 23:55:45",20.1
3,"2020-05-16 23:55:51",12.9
```

Is there something wrong with my query in clickhouse?

When I checked the log, I found below warning.

```
2021.05.10 10:19:50.534441 [ 1534 ] {} <Warning> (readings_queue): Can't get assignment. It can be caused by some issue with consumer group (not enough partitions?). Will keep trying.
```

Comment: Unclear what's producing data into that table or topic

Comment: look at this article - https://altinity.com/blog/clickhouse-kafka-engine-faq

Comment: + try to add param *kafka_row_delimiter = '\n'*

Comment: @OneCricketeer The data should be separated by ','. For example, for the first row, readid:1, time:"2020-05-16 23:55:44", temp:14.2.

Comment: @vladmir Seems that the extra param doesn't help.

Comment: That doesn't answer my comment. What is producing data? Where are you actually inserting data into either the topic or the table? For example, in the link just given, there's the materialized view creation that does `AS SELECT * FROM test.kafka;`to move data from the topic to the clickhouse table. And I'm not sure if clickhouse consumes existing topic data, so you may need to produce new data to the topic

Comment: @OneCricketeer I tried to produced new data to topic after the table was built in clickhouse. But it doesnt work also.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example to work with:

```sql
-- Actual table to store the data fetched from an Apache Kafka topic
CREATE TABLE data(
  a DateTime,
  b Int64,
  c Sting
) Engine=MergeTree ORDER BY (a,b);

-- Materialized View to insert any consumed data by Kafka Engine to 'data' table
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW data_mv TO data AS
SELECT
  a,
  b,
  c
FROM data_kafka;

-- Kafka Engine which consumes the data from 'data_topic' of Apache Kafka
CREATE TABLE data_kafka(
  a DateTime,
  b Int64,
  c Sting
) ENGINE = Kafka
SETTINGS kafka_broker_list = '10.1.2.3:9092,10.1.2.4:9092,
10.1.2.5:9092',
 kafka_topic_list = 'data_topic'
 kafka_num_consumers = 1,
 kafka_group_name = 'ch-result5',
 kafka_format = 'JSONEachRow';
```